# Why do i get this error when initialising a stack?

Tags: c++

I know the following code is not correct, but I really want to know WHY it isn't possible.

```
struct nod {
    int val;
    nod a;
};
```

Of course, I should've made it `nod *a`, but why do I get field `a` has incomplete type when I compile?
I can however make `a` a pointer in the structure which simulate linking to another portion of memory after I free some space using new operator.

Comment: I think a better question would be why **should** it be possible?

Comment: node not nod - Also having a struct with a member of the struct's type? @JohnDibling said "Is it possible"?

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528633/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-the-class-itself/26528810#26528810). Related: [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981242/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-initialising-a-stack).

Comment: `sizeof(nod)` would be ~= to `sizeof(int) + sizeof(nod)`. It's recursive, so `sizeof(nod)` = `sizeof(int) + sizeof(nod)` = `sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(nod)` = `sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(nod)` = ... forever and ever.

Comment: @molbdnilo: you just linked the question to itself...

Comment: @hagubear:  The question was not if it's possible.  The question was why it's not possible.

Comment: @Cornstalks:  See what he did there?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler's error message is quite clear:

```
 field 'a' has incomplete type
```

By the time the compiler reaches that line of code, `nod` has not yet been fully defined.  In order to have a member of type `nod` in a class, the compiler needs to know at minumum just how big a `nod` is.  Since `nod` isn't fully defined yet, the compiler has no way of knowing how big `nod` will be.

The reason why using nod*`instead of a`nod`works is because the compiler doesn't need to know what is in a`nod`in order to know how big a pointer-to-`nod` is.

Even if `nod` was fully-defined, you still couldn;t do this.  One `nod` would have another `nod`, which would have another `nod`, and so on forever.  It's like standing in front of a mirror with a mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it: if `nod` contains another `nod`, which in turn contains another `nod` which... (ad libitum), `nod` effectively would be of infinite size!

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler knows how much memory needs to be allocated for `nod*` (usually 32-bit or 64-bit), even if `nod` itself is not fully defined yet. In other words, the compiler only needs to leave a 32-bit or 64-bit slots at that pointer field.

On the other hand, if the field is a `nod`, then the compiler must know how much memory `nod` object needs to hold, which is not possible when `nod` itself is not fully defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough regarding what you are willing to do.

An Incomplete type error means you are trying to declare a variable whose type has only been forward declared.

If you do a forward declaration only, such as:

```
class nod;
```

The compiler knows that nod is a class defined elsewhere. You can then declare a pointer variable of type `nod*`. You cannot dereference it, nor declare a variable of type `nod`. For this, the compiler needs the full class declaration:

```
class nod
{
    int someVariable;
    char someOtherVariable;
}
```